# Why doesn't Safari display my SVG path element?

Tags: svg, safari

Consider the following SVG image which has an arrow and two eyes:

[image: Aang]

In Google Chrome this SVG image is displayed correctly. However, in Safari 12.1 (12607.1.40.1.5) on Mac OS X 10.12.6, only the eyes are displayed. The arrow is missing, and I have no idea why.

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Actual:

[image: Actual]

As far as I know, my SVG code is correct. Here's my SVG code for reference:

```html
 <!-- Copyright (c) 2019 Aadit M Shah -->
    <svg width="128" height="128" viewBox="-28 -15.5 128 128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <defs>
            <!-- avatar state glow -->
            <filter id="glow" x="-5000%" y="-5000%" width="10000%" height="10000%">
                <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#A1C1E6" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
                <feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
                <feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="2"></feMorphology>
                <feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feMerge>
                    <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
                </feMerge>
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <!-- left eye -->
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#glow)" d="
            M 28.316 90.594
            C 24.937 91.228 21.347 97.563 14.801 96.718
            C  8.255 95.873  2.130 85.103  0.230 86.159
            C -1.671 87.215  8.677 81.302 14.379 82.569
            C 20.081 83.836 25.360 91.650 28.316 90.594
            Z
        "/>
        <!-- right eye -->
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#glow)" d="
            M 43.526 90.594
            C 46.905 91.228 50.495 97.563 57.041 96.718
            C 63.587 95.873 69.712 85.103 71.612 86.159
            C 73.513 87.215 63.165 81.302 57.463 82.569
            C 51.761 83.836 46.482 91.650 43.526 90.594
            Z
        "/>
        <!-- arrow tattoo -->
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#glow)" d="
            M 26.204 0
            C 23.932  5.371 22.291 15.107 21.320 25.147
            C 20.198 36.728 19.966 48.712 20.677 54.869
            C 14.417 55.442  7.485 54.372  0.440 53.376
            C  6.953 62.322 26.132 81.074 35.921 87.637
            C 45.710 81.074 64.889 62.322 71.402 53.376
            C 64.357 54.372 57.425 55.442 51.165 54.869
            C 51.876 48.712 51.644 36.728 50.523 25.147
            C 49.551 15.107 47.910  5.371 45.638 0
            Q 35.921 -2.000 26.204 0
            Z
        "/>
    </svg>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Safari?

Comment: Presumably it just won't create a filter that big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was your filter. I've removed the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` and I'm using [filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/filterUnits)

```html
 <svg width="128" height="128" viewBox="-28 -15.5 128 128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <defs>
            <!-- avatar state glow -->
            <filter id="glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#A1C1E6" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
                <feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
                <feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="2"></feMorphology>
                <feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feMerge>
                    <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
                </feMerge>
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <!-- left eye -->
        <path fill="#fff" filter="url(#glow)" d="
            M 28.316 90.594
            C 24.937 91.228 21.347 97.563 14.801 96.718
            C  8.255 95.873  2.130 85.103  0.230 86.159
            C -1.671 87.215  8.677 81.302 14.379 82.569
            C 20.081 83.836 25.360 91.650 28.316 90.594
            Z
        "/>
        <!-- right eye -->
        <path fill="#fff" filter="url(#glow)" d="
            M 43.526 90.594
            C 46.905 91.228 50.495 97.563 57.041 96.718
            C 63.587 95.873 69.712 85.103 71.612 86.159
            C 73.513 87.215 63.165 81.302 57.463 82.569
            C 51.761 83.836 46.482 91.650 43.526 90.594
            Z
        "/>
        <!-- arrow tattoo -->
        <path fill="#fff" filter="url(#glow)" d="
            M 26.204, 0
            C 23.932,  5.371 22.291, 15.107 21.320, 25.147
            C 20.198, 36.728 19.966, 48.712 20.677, 54.869
            C 14.417, 55.442  7.485, 54.372  0.440, 53.376
            C  6.953, 62.322 26.132, 81.074 35.921, 87.637
            C 45.710, 81.074 64.889, 62.322 71.402, 53.376
            C 64.357, 54.372 57.425, 55.442 51.165, 54.869
            C 51.876, 48.712 51.644, 36.728 50.523, 25.147
            C 49.551, 15.107 47.910,  5.371 45.638, 0
            Q 35.921, -2.000 26.204, 0
            Z
        "/>
   
 
    </svg>
```

Comment: Makes sense. A ten thousand percent size filter is insanely huge. Thanks.